# AES and RSA encryption in ASP

Tags: asp.net

I am starting a communication test work with a webservice, and this interaction includes encryption protocols AES and RSA. However, the site that has the webservice (followzup) only provides examples in PHP and Java.
How to proceed this test? What protocol should I use first?

Comment: Sorry, the communication test is described in followzup.com ("All about" tab).

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please don't expect anyone here to read the documentation for you. You could start with trying to "translate" the provided PHP and/or JAVA code you linked to and come back and ask a more specific question if you get stuck...Hth.